# Firefox 31.0: new Date parsing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, firefox

Have troubles with Firefox:

1. *Simple Date*

```
new Date("Jun, 2014"); // Invalid Date
```

2. *jquery ui datepickers*

```
$(item).datepicker('option', 'minDate', null); //Remove date from datepicker, it remains empty
```

- **Question [main]:** How to convert "Jun, 2014" to Date on Firefox?
- **Question 2** How to solve the second problem?

P.S. In Chrome 36.0.1985.125 all works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `new Date("Jun, 2014");` is not a date as you didn't specify the day, looks like they are being stricter with that.

   `new Date("Jun 1, 2014");`
2. The datepicker has no minimum by default and also it takes a hash (object) of options if you did need to provide any, but it seems like you don't. http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/883s8dar/1/

To ensure that you have the minimum date you need to set `minDate` to null, see source of v1.11:

```
minDate: null, // The earliest selectable date, or null for no limit
```

So therefore you can do:

```
$('.data-picker').datepicker({
    minDate: null   
});
```

Though if you didn't set it that is default so not sure why you need to do that.

Comment: thanks. Can you suggest answer to the second question?

Comment: Sure but can you explain in different words what your problem is I didn't understand. What are you trying to do with the date picker?

Comment: When I write `$(item).datepicker('option', 'minDate', null)` - I gonna set `minDate` option of datepicker to `null`. Null means there is no restrictions for the minimum date user can choose in datepicker. PROBLEM: instead of setting minimum date that string make datepicker to be emptied. Means before I executed that string it had showed "Jun, 2014", but after that string datepicker is empty.

Comment: @V_B you want to have no minimum on the date, or you want to limit it to Jun, 2014?

Comment: I wanna to have no minimum on the date

Comment: @V_B a) datepicker takes an object of options and b) it has no minimum by default

Comment: the problem is that minimum could be set somewhere else, so I need to reset it. I think it would be better to accept your answer and move this about datepickers to separate one